# Multiprocessing - run a specific file?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Is it possible to start a new python process dedicated to run a specific file or module rather than a function available in the current file?

The goal would be to:

- reduce application complexity by separating the child process code from the primary process code & removing the need for guards like `if __name__ == '__main__'`, thereby making the application easier to maintain & more difficult to break. I dont want the the file responsible for creating the child process to be interpreted by the child process
- still be able to benefit from shared memory

The solution does not necessarily need to involve the multiprocessing module.

Im currently considering just using `os.system` to spin up another python instance. But then Im not sure how I would be able to benefit from shared memory.

Comment: That's... just running `python somefile.py` as a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) the same way you "exec" any other program in Python? You don't get shared memory, but then you probably need to explain what actual thing you're trying to do before that requirement really makes sense.

Comment: Hi & thanks. Do you know if I still use shared memory that way (dictionaries, lists & variables that are shared across processes)?

Comment: That seems to go against your "separating the child process code from the primary process code" goal.

Comment: No, because it's a separate process, so you really need to explain why you need to run an entire file "on its own" while still have shared memory, because that feels like you're asking an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/) where you're trying to do something and you're asking about how to implement your imagined solution, instead of asking what the best solution is.

Comment: Also, by default, separate Python processes don't share memory, even *with* `multiprocessing`. If you want to share memory between processes, you have to do that manually, but the [tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) for doing that are very low-level and don't allow sharing things like dicts, lists, or variables.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Its a design choice, Im writing a reuseable library to act as an alternative to the multiprocessing module (adding more features on top). One of the things I wanted to implement is the functionality Im asking about here.

Theres no particular single application that Im writing this for, one could call it an experiment :)

Comment: Hi @user2357112 , in the python documentation there are several mentions of types implemented on top of shared memory. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#:~:text=multiprocessing.Array

Unless Im misinterpreting the docs, I believe dicts, lists & various simpler types are available

Comment: It sounds like you might just want to run [`runpy.run_path` or `runpy.run_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) in a `multiprocessing.Process`. That should get you about as close to your goal as you actually *can* get.

Comment: " Unless Im misinterpreting the docs, I believe dicts, lists & various simpler types are available" - you are indeed misinterpreting the docs. Dicts and lists cannot be held in shared memory.

Comment: @user2357112 Surprised that you seem to be suggesting that fundamental Python objects can't be shared across sub-processes. Isn't that what the Manager class is for? Unless you're classifying Manager as "low-level"

Comment: @DarkKnight: `multiprocessing.Manager` doesn't use shared memory. It creates a server process and holds objects in the server process's memory. Other processes pass messages to the server when they want to interact with the objects.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe you're struggling to understand what I said. The issue here is one of sharing data across multiple processes and although OP alludes to "shared memory" I'm confident that she using the term generically. You seem to be suggesting that sharing (for example) dictionaries is challenging and I argue that it is not

Comment: What do you mean by "benefit from shared memory"? Most operating systems these days share pages of mapped memory between processes using a copy-on-write mechanism. That is definitely a benefit (reduces memory usage) but it doesn't allow for exchanging data. You can use `mmap` to share data between unrelated processes, but that basically gives you a `bytearray`. You could conceivably combine that with `pickle` to exchange Python objects. Although doing that would be unsafe for the reason explained in the `pickle` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some misconceptions here. Let's address them separately.

---

First *"shared memory"*. Shared memory is created via the operating system's virtual memory manager. In order to use it, a (typically large) block of memory is mapped into multiple processes' address spaces and those sharing processes can all directly access the same physical RAM via a pointer. Such large blocks are typically, but not always, used for i/o buffers or image buffers.

Python objects, such as dicts and lists cannot be stored in these as access to their management data, reference counts and so on would not be synchronised. Buffers underlying Numpy arrays can be stored in such shared memory.

Processes wishing to share memory must necessarily be on the same computer.

Processes wishing to use shared memory do not have to be started via the multiprocessing manager - they can be started entirely independently. In fact that is the case in the standard example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

---

Secondly, Python objects such as dicts and lists can be shared amongst processes via a Manager. This is not shared memory per se, it is more like a proxy that accesses objects that exist in its own memory on your behalf rather than memory mapped into your process which you address directly.

Such objects can be shared between processes on different computers.

Processes wishing to share such managed objects do not need to have been started via the multiprocessing tools, they can be started entirely independently and connect to a Manager of their own free will at any point.