# Python Multiprocessing - How to use Pool to run on two functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am just figuring out how to use Python multiprocessing and have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

res1 = set()
res2 = set()
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def squared(x):
    res1.add(x ** x)

def cubed(x):
    res2.add(x * x * x)

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    pool.map(squared, nums)
    print(res1, res2)

    pool.map(cubed, nums)
    print(res1, res2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
set() set()
set() set()
```

At the end I just want to update `res1` and `res2` where `res1`is updated first using `squared` in parallel for each number in `nums` and wait for that to finish, then update `res2` using `cubed` in parallel for each number in `nums`.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: This doesn't work. Each process of the pool has its own `res1` and `res2` variables and sets. The sets in the main process aren't modified.

Comment: Using a multiprocessing `Manager` you can create at least a list or dict object which can be shared between the processes.

Comment: I don't think I necessarily need to share `res1` or `res2` but just update res1 using `squared` in parallel and wait for that to finish, then update `res2` using `cubed` in parallel.

Comment: Let `squared` and `cubed` return their results. The `map` call will return them as a list which can then be processed further.

Comment: Multiple processes **don't share state**. It is the same as if you did `python myscirpt.py` in the terminal, then opened another terminal, and did `python myscript.py` again. Those are two *different processes*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga They don't share state by default, but they **can** share memory and they **can** share lists and dicts if they choose to via a manager.

Comment: I wrote an answer about sharing data between processes  a couple of days ago... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75774618/2836621

Comment: Of course, different processes *can* share state,  but you have to make that happen. A manager, for example, just creates a server process which hosts the Python object, and the processes interact with the host through proxy objects, handling the IPC and basic concurrency safety. So in that way, it is like a database like postgres

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, agreed.

Comment: I don't believe Python `sets` can be shared via a manager. It is however very easy to share sets using **Redis** which would allow the sharers to be on different machines/networks and to use different languages - Python, PHP, bash, Java, Ruby, Rust etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are aware that due to the trivialness of your worker functions `squared` and `cubed` that using multiprocessing will result in a longer execution time. I will also assume that your actual worker functions are CPU-intensive enough such that what you gain by running these functions in parallel more than offset the addition overhead incurred by multiprocessing.

That said, there are multiple approaches you can take:

**Have the Main Process Perform the Set Processing**

This was suggested by Michael Butscher:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def squared(x):
    return x * x

def cubed(x):
    return x * x * x

def main():
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    res1 = set(pool.map(squared, nums))
    res2 = set(pool.map(cubed, nums))
    print(res1)
    print(res2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
{64, 1, 8, 27, 125}
```

**Use a Managed Dictionary As a Set Replacement**

If all you are doing is adding elements to a set (to prevent duplicates), you can achieve the same result with a managed dictionary since its keys must be unique:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def squared(res1, x):
    res1[x * x] = None # The actual value does not matter

def cubed(res2, x):
    res2[x * x * x] = None

def main():
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        res1 = manager.dict()
        res2 = manager.dict()

        pool.map(partial(squared, res1), nums)
        pool.map(partial(cubed, res2), nums)

        print(list(res1.keys()))
        print(list(res2.keys()))

        # Or create actual sets:
        s1 = set(res1)
        s2 = set(res2)
        print(s1)
        print(s2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
[4, 1, 16, 9, 25]
[64, 125, 1, 27, 8]
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
{64, 1, 8, 27, 125}
```

**Create Your Own Managed Set**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from functools import partial

class SetManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def squared(res1, x):
    res1.add(x * x)

def cubed(res2, x):
    res2.add(x * x * x)

def main():
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    SetManager.register('Set', set)

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    with SetManager() as manager:
        res1 = manager.Set()
        res2 = manager.Set()

        pool.map(partial(squared, res1), nums)
        pool.map(partial(cubed, res2), nums)

        print(res1)
        print(res2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
{64, 1, 8, 27, 125}
```

Note that the proxy that is automatically generated above for the managed set only supports basic methods such as `add`, `clear`, `remove`, etc. You will not be able to do operations such as `res1 += res2`.

Comment: Best answer I've seen on StackOverflow for some time, thank you.